# Run a long running job using the fire and forget strategy with Thymeleaf in Reactor and r2dbc

Tags: thymeleaf, spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc

I am trying to achieve a fire and forget type of effect with webflux, thymeleaf and r2dbc. I have two endpoints, one to add an employee and another to list all employees. I want to simulate a slow database access so I have a thread sleep of several seconds before I call the DB.

Now, the effect I expect to see when I call `/add` is that my controller returns immediately and the page `add` is rendered at once. However, I'm not sure how to achieve this. With the current code `nap()` happens before I can return a `Mono`. In other words, I'm trying to run a long running job in the background without blocking the controller.

I have the following model:

```
@Data
public class Employee {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

The annotated controller has following methods:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/")
public String home(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("employees", repo.findAll());
    return "home";
}

@GetMapping(value = "/add")
public Mono<String> add() {
    return Mono
        .defer(this::getEmployee)
        .doOnNext(e -> repo.save(e).subscribe())
        .thenReturn("add");
}

private Mono<Employee> getEmployee() {
    final var e = new Employee();
    e.setName("John");
    nap(); // calls thread sleep for a few sec
    return Mono.just(e);
}
```

My question is how can I wrap the long running job but at the same time preserve a Controller based notation (instead of functional) and also render the `add` page immediately? I am aware of some similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57566465/fire-and-forget-with-reactor) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61470200/webflux-reactive-objects-not-resolved-before-rendering-thymeleaf-view), but I don't seem to be able to achieve the behaviour I need.

**Edit:**
lkatiforis' suggestion and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64643879/how-to-wrap-blocking-io-operation-for-webflux-applicaiton) SO question were a push in the right direction. I had to adjust their example a bit because the employee didn't persist. The change is in `add()`:

```
public String add() {
    Mono.just(employee)
        .delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
        .doOnNext(e -> repo.save(e).subscribe())
        .subscribe();
    return "add";
}
```

`employee` is just an instance of `Employee` with a populated name. The `delayElement` operator pauses for 5 seconds without blocking. Finally, I had to call `subscribe()` on `repo.save()` and at the end in order for it to work. I assume that if `subscribe()` is only called on `doOnNext()` then the main chain that starts with `Mono.just()` is never executed.

Comment: what is your long running job? what's its signature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `nap()` method executes `Thread.sleep` or something similar, right? `Thread.sleep` is blocking the main thread making the application unresponsive. You can use `delayElements` operator to simulate a long-running operation:

```java
private Mono<Employee> getEmployee() {
    final var e = new Employee();
    e.setName("John");
    return Mono.just(e).delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
}
```